iOS: How to search app with text different app name
App name: SmartNews
With CFBundleName and CFBundleDisplayName is SmartNews
But when I search with text "スマート" (which means Smart) in spotlight search, the app is displayed on result.
I have tried Core spotlight, but the results were not as expected.
How to do that in Xcode, thanks


I don't understand.  What component is causing a problem here?  What do you want it to do that it is not doing?

FWIW, you get hits for スマートニュース because this particular app has been localized for Japanese.
To answer the basic question: If you just want to make sure that you your app has a romaji name for English-based devices and a katakana version for Japanese-based devices, you simply:

add Japanese localization to your app; and
in your localized InfoPlist.strings file (not an .xcstrings file), add entry for "CFBundleDisplayName" and/or "CFBundleName" with the katakana rendition.

When you do that, devices currently using English can search for the romaji name and devices using Japanese allow you to search for the katakana rendition.


Now, your screen snapshot is showing a different scenario, specifically where you searched for the katakana string on a device currently using English. If that is the case, you might also consider using NSUserActivity with Japanese keywords, but I confess that I was unable to reproduce this “search for Japanese name on English-language device” behavior.
